# Pandas dataframe doesnot append and missing the counter

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append to a dataframe for getting a expected result like below.

How do i append it right? Currently i am not getting the correct dataframe in this for loop below
Please help

Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
no = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    no = no + 1
    tt = "ab"
    lst = [no, lst]
    df = df.append(lst)
```

Expected result

```
no tt
1  ab
2  ab
3  ab
.  .
.  .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
no = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    no = no + 1
    tt = "ab"
    lst = {'no':no,'tt':tt}
    df = df.append(lst,ignore_index=True)
```

OR

For more efficiently just simply use `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'no':range(1,10),'tt':'ab'})
```

Comment: how do i preseve the column order as dict, because i am getting the column order changed

Comment: @prog you can use ordered dict see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28231217/14289892

Answer (score 1):

do this modification in your provide code
as I did

```
df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['no','tt'])
no = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    no = no + 1
    lst = [no, 'ab']
    df_length = len(df)
    df.loc[df_length] = lst
```

Hope this will be helpful for you